# What is my grade percentage

Tags: arithmetic

If I get 45 percent on an assignment worth 85 % and 45 percent in an assignment worth 15% what is my final grade.

or otherwise worded as I have 2 assignments one worth 85% the other worth 15% what is my final grade if i get 45 percent on the both?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

Your total grade would be:
$$
45\% \> \>of\> \>85\% + 45\% \>\>of\>\> 15\% \\
or, \> 0.45 \times 0.85 + 0.45 \times0.15 = 0.45(0.85+0.15) = 0.45 \times 1.00 = 0.45 = 45 \%    
$$
XD

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Take the weighted average.

Comment: In a case like this, where the OP is apparently struggling with how grades are computed, it would be good to include a little more than just "Easy: just do (some procedure)."

Comment: Especially if the issue is "how do I do said procedure"

Comment: I was dropping a hint so that he can work on it rather than me giving away the answer. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then you get $45\%$ overall. Whenever all your grades are the same, this will be true.

Comment: Even when one is worth more? so if they where both worth 50 percent

Comment: @sammy Yes, the weights of the grades don't matter if they're all the same grade.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have one test of 85 marks and one test of 15 marks.

$45%$ of $85$ is $85*45/100$ marks and $45%$ of $15$ marks is $15*45/100$

add both marks to get final %

OR

you have 2 tests and in one you get x% and in another one you get y%, so your average % would be (x+y)/2